# package.json not npm installing

Tags: python, node.js

Okay, when i try and install the nodes through NPM install, Now i have only jut began programming and this just baffled me..., Any ideas or thoughts? (Please dumb it down)

```
C:\Users\Jason\WebstormProjects\Test Project\node_modules\kerberos>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:116:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:71:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Jason\WebstormProjects\Test Project\node_modules\kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Also i have installed Python numerous times believing that was the issue

Comment: You have to set environment variable pointing to the directory with your Python binary. `Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.`

Comment: One of the options in the Python installer for Windows is "Add Python.exe to Path." It'll be disabled by default. You'll want to enable it.

Comment: So in essence i would need to do 
npm config set python C:\Programs\Python2.7\python2.7.exe

Comment: It isn't an npm-specific setting. The `$PATH` variable is a system setting defined for the OS (Windows). `node-gyp` will use its value when trying to find Python, so the directory where Python was installed to needs to be added to it. The Python installer will do that for you if you run it again, select to "Change" the installation, and enable "Add python.exe to Path."

Comment: The new version i was using never had this option so i have downloaded 2.7 so hopefully that will allow it to be accepted

Comment: Now the issue of Kerberos ?